# drizzle.contracts is empty object after creating new instance of Drizzle

Tags: web3js, drizzle

After creating a new istance of Dirzzle and passing the needed options:

```
const drizzle = new Drizzle(options);
```

The object `drizzle.contracts` is an empty object instead of being an array of the contracts specified inside the `options`.
Because of that, trying to access the events of a contract by calling:

```
drizzle.contracts.MyContract.events
```

Will cause the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'events' of undefined

This is because `drizzle.contracts.MyContract` is undefined. Since, `drizzle.contracts` is an empty object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new instance of the Drizzle object is not initialized immediatly. And it is done asyncornosly.

We have to wait till it is finished its initialization before being able to access it.

This could be done with the following `async` code block that has to be called before accesing any contract inside the new `drizzle` instance.

```
var state = this.drizzle.store.getState();
while (!state.drizzleStatus.initialized) {
  const delay = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));
  await delay;
  state = this.drizzle.store.getState();
  console.log(state.drizzleStatus);
}
```